# Where can I get Ubuntu's Gnome Settings source code?

Tags: gnome, gnome-control-center

I want to learn more about C and GNOME applications in general, for that, I wanted to integrate some stuff from Ubuntu's Appearance tab to Gnome Settings (gnome-control-center) in Fedora, but I just can't seem to find Ubuntu's gnome-control-center (here is the original gnome-control-center gitlab for reference: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/)

Does someone know where I can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for the Ubuntu package is at https://launchpad.net/gnome-control-center

Comment: The latest version of this package is 3.02, which is outdated.

Comment: @gustavo Check the '*Packages in Distributions*'  section at the bottom.